# Bugs when applying intersection observer in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, intersection-observer

I want to render my image only when the user has seen it or when the image element is visible within the user viewport. I already tried it, but the image is only rendered when I already passed all the image element, not one by one when i scroll.

I create a custom directive and place it on my parent div.

This is my intersection observer using Vue directive:

```
inserted: el => {
  let arrayChildren = Array.from(el.children)

  const config = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0,
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src
        observer.unobserve(entry.target)
      }
    })
  }, config)

  function getAllImgQuery() {
    let imageArray = []
    arrayChildren.forEach(element => {
      if (element.nodeName === 'IMG') {
        imageArray.push(element)
      }
    })
    return imageArray
  }

  let imageQuery = getAllImgQuery()

  imageQuery.forEach(image => {
    observer.observe(image)
  })
},
```

And this is my Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="image-container">
    <div class="product">
      <figure class="image-wrapper" v-lazyload>
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <img :data-src="url" style="margin-top: 100px">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import lazyLoadDirective from "../directives/lazyLoadImage.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url:
        "https://s2.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20190823&t=2&i=1422065068&w=1200&r=LYNXNPEF7M1OI"
    };
  },
  directives: {
    lazyload: lazyLoadDirective
  }
};
</script>
```

At the end, the six images loads at the same time only when I already seen it or intersect it (when I was at the bottom of the page). How can i load my image one by one only after i scroll pass it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the threshold you have set. I recommend reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

**Treshold:**

> Either a single number or an array of numbers which indicate at what
>   percentage of the target's visibility the observer's callback should
>   be executed. If you only want to detect when visibility passes the 50%
>   mark, you can use a value of 0.5. If you want the callback to run
>   every time visibility passes another 25%, you would specify the array
>   [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]. The default is 0 (meaning as soon as even one
>   pixel is visible, the callback will be run). A value of 1.0 means that
>   the threshold isn't considered passed until every pixel is visible.

Comment: I think it's not. I've tried to change the threshold, but it just doesn't work